# TinyMCE Standard Emoticons don't show on frontend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, codeigniter, web-applications, tinymce

I'm integrating tinyMCE in a CI\AngularJS app. the standard emoticons plugins adds something like this to my text:

```
 <img src="bower_components/tinymce/plugins/emoticons/img/smiley-frown.gif" alt="frown">
```

the path added to the image is correct when reached from the server side when creating the content, but it is not correct when approached from the frontend to view the created content there.
to make the image show on my frontend I can change the url to be:

```
 <img src="admin_client/app/bower_components/tinymce/plugins/emoticons/img/smiley-frown.gif" alt="frown">
```

but then I won't see it when creating the content on server side.

Another solution that works but does not seem right at all is to simply add a folder 'bower_components/tinymce/plugins/emoticons/img/' to my project root...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting

```
relative_urls: false
```

in your `tinyMCE.init()` function:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    [...]
    relative_urls: false
});
```

This basically tells TinyMCE to use absolute paths for images, emoticons, etc, rather than relative paths.  I had a similar problem and doing this solved it.